# Getting Error While testing Google In-App purchase Subscriptions

Tags: testing, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, subscription, in-app

I am implementing google In-app purchase subscriptions in Android app for testing product of id android.test.purchased but getting following error.

> {   "code": -e,   "message": "could not complete purchase",   "text":
>   "Signature verification failed for sku android.test.purchase(response:
>   -1003:Purchase signature verification failed)",   "response": -1003,   "errorCode": -6 }

I have uploaded app in internal testing of Google play console and downloaded app from there. I have added all required permissions but still getting this error. Any help would be appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the method that you used to make the purchase from Billing API ?

Comment: I am using In-app Billing with AIDL. I want to implement subscriptions. I have used getBuyIntent() method to buy subscription which is added in google play billing.